# SonarQube 7.4 scanning ObjectiveC using fastlane

Tags: ios, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, fastlane

I have many iOS projects with both ObjectiveC and Swift code. I'm using SonarQube 7.4 server and using Fastlane for build, test, scan and deploy. Everything was working fine for 1+ year and suddenly sonar-scanner starts failing with below error:

```
INFO: Sensor CFamily [cpp]
ERROR: The only way to get an accurate analysis of C/C++/Objective-C files is by using the SonarSource build-wrapper
and setting the property "sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output", but it was not specified.
If you don't want to analyze C/C++/Objective-C files, then prevent them from being analyzed by setting the following properties:
sonar.c.file.suffixes=-
sonar.cpp.file.suffixes=-
sonar.objc.file.suffixes=-
```

I tried build-wrapper on one of my projects and it starts giving my compilation errors. Fastlane Gym works fine though. So instead of figuring all this out, is there a plugin in Fastlane for this? Or any way I can ignore this build-wrapper? 
(It was working fine & stopped suddenly so not sure if it's 'really' an issue)

Comment: I don’t know anything about SonarQube but I’ve used fastlane gym a lot. Any guesses about what changed? Did you upgrade fastlane or any other software?

Comment: I'm also using gym and it's working fine. Looking for action which does this build-wrapper compilation for SonarQube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is quite funny as the functionality of SonarQube scanner is broken (or with bugs). I created a new project and used **build-wrapper** to build my project. It created 2 files in a directory

- bw_output/

  - build-wrapper-dump.json
  - build-wrapper.log

Content of build-wrapper-dump.json is

```
{"version":0,
"captures":[]}
```

I used this file for my other projects and `sonar-scanner` worked for all. So it looks like that solution for the above problem is to just commit these 2 files and update `sonar-project.properties` like below:

```
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output
#sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output.bypass=true
```

2nd line is a comment and you can skip it also.

Comment: Why couldn't you just use that second line telling it to ignore wrapper output since you're not using it? Isn't that what bypass means?

Comment: bypass no longer works. It is now mandatory to have this folder from build-wrapper.